# In what way is the calculation of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2}$ wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

Is something wrong with the calculation below?

$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x}{1-2/x} \\
& = \frac{(\lim_{x \to \infty} 4x)}{(\lim_{x \to \infty} 1-2/x)} \\
& = \frac{(\lim_{x \to \infty} 4x)}{1} \\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \\
& = \infty.
\end{align} $$

I ask because if there isn't then the following would seem correct,

$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} - 4x &= \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} \right) - \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right) \\
& = \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right) - \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right) \\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x - 4x \\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} 0 \\
& = 0.
\end{align} $$

But it is not, since

$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} - 4x &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2 - 4x(x-2)}{x-2} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{8x}{x-2} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{8}{1-2/x} \\
&= 8. \\
\end{align} $$

In what way is this wrong? Where is the mistake?

Comment: I think you have pretty well pinned down the mistake by your careful exposition.  After all, $x$ and $x+8$ both tend to infinity, but that doesn't mean that you can find the limit of their difference by taking the difference of the two (infinite) limits.

Comment: But getting to the limit of their difference is exactly how I would find the difference of their limits. I was thinking despite the first calculation being correct, the mistake is substituting something for infinity in the second calculation.

Comment: The limit of the difference $(x+8)-x$ is obvious (since the expression simplifies to a constant).  But it doesn't make sense to subtract $\infty - \infty$, the difference of the limits.  Something that makes sense is not best found by asking for something that does not make sense.

Comment: That makes sense. So can I or can't I use the rules for calculating with limits when one of the terms tends to infinity? And if I can, what is the mistake after all?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused on limit laws. You should look that up. It'll tell you why you've made the mistakes above.

Comment: As you can check, there is no rule that applies to a difference of two expressions that both tend to infinity.  The difference might have a finite limit, it might tend to plus infinity, it might tend to minus infinity, or it might fail to have any limit at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. Is the mistake by any chance in third line of the first calculation? Where the limit of the fraction above that has a numerator tending to infinity and a denominator tending to one and so the quotient tends to infinity, but not to $(\lim_{x\to\infty} 4x)/1$.

Comment: @henriq.cd: What part in the three answers below you don't understand?

Comment: @henriq.cd You can do operations with limits unless you have an indeterminate form. In your first calculation you have $\infty/1$ which is not indeterminate ($\infty/1=\infty$). Look at Jack's wikipedia link for the rules and also you may look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) for a list of indeterminate forms

Comment: @Momo: your wikipedia article says the limit in the second calculation can be transformed into $0/0$ by multiplying and dividing the term inside the limit by $(4x)(4x^2)/(x-2)$. How can it evaluate to $8$?

Comment: By transforming an undeterminate form into another one, one does not necessarily make the limit easier to calculate.

Comment: I think I see what's happening. Using the limit laws in first line of the second calculation creates an indeterminate form if I were to evaluate the limits, but that is not what is causing the mistake I am referring to in my original post (obtaining $0$) since the limit is only taken when it evaluates to $0$. The mistake actually happens in my use of the limit laws in the first calculation, which is correct before reaching the third line where the denominator only equals $1$ when the numerator equals $\infty$. So the $4x$ limit doesn't equal the limit in the first line.

Answer (score 13):

It is incorrect that

> $$
> \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} - 4x = \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x^2}{x-2} \right) - \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right)
> $$

since in order to apply the limit rule
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(f(x)-g(x)\big)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)
$$
one *needs* <s>both</s> at least one of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ being real numbers. ([Added later:] In the case $\infty-(-\infty)$, one needs to *define* the arithmatic operation for the extended real numbers first.)

---

[Added:]
It is dangerous to view $\infty$ as a number unless you know exactly what *[extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)* are and what [arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations) are (and are not) allowed for them. There are more examples for nonsense by considering $\infty$ as a real number:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\cdot\frac{1}{x}\right)=\infty\cdot 0=0;
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(2x-x\big)=\infty-\infty=0
$$

---

[Added later:]
Also, the step
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x}{1-2/x} 
= \frac{(\lim_{x \to \infty} 4x)}{(\lim_{x \to \infty} 1-2/x)}
$$
would not be mathematically correct *unless* one is working in the extended real numbers and has defined what is $\dfrac{\infty}{a}$ for a non-zero real number $a$.

Comment: Splitting works even if the limits are infinite, unless you have an indeterminate form. In this case there is an undeterminate form.

Comment: Much better after correction. Although "you *need*  at least one of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ being real numbers." is still not correct. For example $\infty+\infty$ is not undeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

$\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form, so the result of it can be anything.

Your mistake is exactly here:

$$\left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right) - \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} 4x \right)= \lim_{x \to \infty} (4x - 4x)$$

On the left side you have $\infty-\infty$, which has to be solved on a case by case basis by returning to the original limit. So splitting in this case does not work.

Comment: No - their mistake is before that, when they split the limit term by term without making sure that the limits of the terms exist.

Comment: It works even if the limits are infinite, unless you have an undeterminate form. And this case has an undeterminate form, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can't split a limit term-by-term like that unless both terms converge.  In this case, neither does, so you can't.